# How to test for routing error in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controllers

I'm simplifying a resource by removing the show action since its not needed. only listing, creating and editing are needed. I still have my `SHOW` test  in my rspecs and its now failing (obviously since I've added an `:except => [:show]` to my routes file.

This is what I'm getting as a failure:

```
1) CampaignsController GET show assigns the requested campaign as @campaign
     Failure/Error: get :show, {:id => campaign.to_param}, valid_session
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:id=>"458", :controller=>"campaigns", :action=>"show"}
     # ./spec/controllers/campaigns_controller_spec.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) CampaignsController routing routes to #show
     Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/campaigns/1").to route_to("campaigns#show", :id => "1")
       No route matches "/campaigns/1"
     # ./spec/routing/campaigns_routing_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I make these tests pass so that I'm **expecting** a routing error?

Answer (score 13):

You could do

```
expect{ get :show }.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
```

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-error

You might also consider routing specs: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/routing-specs

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested the Minitest equivalent would be something like:

```rb
def CampaignsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  assert_raises ActionController::RoutingError do
    get "/campaigns/1"
  end
end
```